Mostrar el fondo de un elemento a través de un texto de otro - Css, TailwindCss
Quiero hacer que el texto <h1> sea transparente y me permita ver la etiqueta imagen <img>.
Hice un bg-clip pero quiero que se vea la de atras, como hacer un agujero en el <section>
<img class="-z-10 fixed" src="./src/imgs/mainImage.png" alt="" />

<section class="bg-white relative top-[656px] py-[100px] px-[250px] flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-24">
      <h1 class="text-8xl font-extrabold tracking-tighter text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-[url(./imgs/mainImage.png)]">
        TORTUGAS MARINAS
      </h1>
</section>

